# Refresh a web page 3 or 4 times a second using Python and Selenium Web Driver

Tags: python, selenium

Is there a way to refresh a web page 3 or 4 times a second using Python and Selenium Web Driver?

Thank you very much.

Comment: So what have you tried so far and what's the issue you encountered? I assume you'd be using `driver.refresh()` - is it not fast enough, or too fast, or what?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What have you tried and failed?

Comment: driver.refresh() works fine but it refreshes the web page once a second, which is way too slow. I need to get some text in the web page ASAP. That's why I need.

Answer (score 1):

Super easy answer: No. The time that the refresh() function takes is machine dependent obviously.
You can anyway set a **max** of 3-4 refreshes per second, but it's really hard that your machine can refresh a page 4 times and analyze its content in between all in a matter of a second.
Maybe using Google Engine service. Either renting a super-computer or use 4 mid-level hardware.
Consider it, i've used remote VMs a lot of times for testing purposes.

Comment: How about 2 times a second? Is it possible? driver.refresh() works once a second, which is way too slow. Thank you very much for your concern.

Comment: I've used refresh() on a really simple page with <10 WebElements and it did more than one refresh per second.

Comment: I repeat, if you want to achieve this, use Google Compute Engine.you can use up to 4 VMs simultaneosly for free.